# c++ Last created object

Tags: c++, oop

I'm trying to figure out one thing. I am trying for 2 days and already searched a lot, so if there is already answer, than I'm sorry i didn't find it.

What I'm trying to figure out is this:

```
    class Unit {

public:
    static vector< Unit* > Units_array;
    static Unit*  Last_created_unit;

    Unit();

    Unit(string,int,int);

private:
 some private vars
}
```

and than i have .cpp file with definitions aswell.
I want to know: When I call constructor, is there a way to save new object to variable Last_created_unit or push it to Units_array. I thought it would be best to use pointers cause i want it to just be pointer to actual new object i have created. But when I start changing members of object it act like i have two different objects, cause there are different values in it.

```
Unit::Unit(string name, int GUID, int faction){

    Last_created_unit = this;
}
```

This is the way i tried to save it to the variable, but how I said it acted like two different objects. Because when i change some member of actualy created object, than the member changed through saved pointer had default value and vice versa.

I would like to do somethhing like following, but right in constructor.

```
Last_created_unit = new Unit("some_name", 1, 1);
```

Just save newly created object (probably pointer to it) to this variable when its created.

I will show you way its acting

```
//create new object
Unit player = Unit("something",100,1);
//our line Last_created_unit = this; have its value from constructor, seems fine.
//than we change, for example int Health (Default 100) through our function SetHealth()
Last_created_unit->SetHealth(90);
//than we retrieve our Health GetHealth()
player.GetHealth(); // output = 100
Last_created_unit->getHealth() // output = 90
```

I hope this shows what am I trying to figure out. If any other info needed just ask.

Thanks for help.

Comment: This doesn't look possible, but it's hard for me to tell without a runnable example. Could you put your several code blocks together into a single example that I can compile and run for myself?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem here: https://ideone.com/lJVKUR

Comment: "When I call constructor" – **you?** Are you sure you meant "call"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write

```
Unit player = Unit("something",100,1);
```

you are (formally) creating a temporary object that is then copied to `player`. (This copy can be elided, depending on optimization levels, but it still occurs for purposes of access control.)

If object identity is important to you you should delete the copy constructor and seat all your class instances in smart pointers:

```
Unit(Unit const&) = delete;

// ...

auto player = std::make_unique<Unit>("something",100,1);
```

Comment: Or without the smarty stuff, `Unit player = Unit("something",100,1);`  ===>  `Unit * player = new Unit("something",100,1);`

Comment: With the smarty stuff if you don't want to worry about the delety stuff, I think.

Comment: Oh, I agree, but there is a difference between explaining what went wrong and saying what should be done instead

Comment: So that means, I when I do Last_created_unit = this; in constructor than I have pointer to that temporary copy of Object, but when I save it to player, I get just a copy?

Comment: @DavidMinařík yes, that's what happens.

Comment: Ok guys, thanks for help, It looks like i got it working. I will mark this as answer, but credits go to @AndyNewman aswell :)

Answer (score 3):

Create a factory that creates objects, and let the factory keep track of created objects.

```
class Factory {
  Unit* createUnit() {
    Unit *newUnit = new Unit();
    // keep track of new objects
    return newUnit
  }
};

class Unit {
  friend Factory
  protected:
    Unit();
};
```

Comment: I agree, but maybe a simple static member function, e.g. `static Unit* Unit::createUnit() {...};`, is already enough (less overhead).

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
Unit player = Unit("something",100,1);
```

means you create a new temporary object and your constructor is called. Then you assign the temporary object to `player` using the default-created copy-constructor which does not track `player` in `Last_created_unit`. Then the temporary object (still tracked in `Last_created_unit`) is destroyed, so any following operations using the pointer `Last_created_unit` cause undefined behavior.

You should construct new object this way:

```
Unit player("something", 100, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `Unit::Last_created_unit` member:

```
Unit::Last_created_unit->SetHealth(90);
player.GetHealth();
```